# tesseract ocr pdf - segmentation fault

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to OCR pdf file with `tesseract`, but it says:

> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine name_to_image_type:Error:Unrecognized
>   image type:upload526.pdf IMAGE::read_header:Error:Can't read this
>   image type:upload526.pdf tesseract:Error:Read of file
>   failed:upload526.pdf Segmentation fault

I need it to make a database to search through pdfs that were scanned manually (to images)... What am I doing wrong? I read that it supports pdfs... No idea what version it is as `tesseract --version` or `tesseract -v` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract does not read PDF. You'll need to convert it to an image format (TIFF, PNG) first. Try GhostScript, ImageMagick, programming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along the lines of this (ImageMagick library):

```
convert -density 300 file.pdf -depth 8 file.tiff  
tesseract file.tiff output
```